# Android Flutter project cannot build with various errors

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I got source from Github and I download the zip file, and open with Android Studio(Latest) after that I command Pub Get to download dependencies. I thought when I push build button, it might work like another flutter android apps.

But it shows me a lot of errors and I tried various methods in Stackoverflow and solutions in Google but all of the solutions are not working.

The source that I use is https://github.com/nn1ks/RemoteFiles

Source code is okay because

I tried online IDE because I thought the problem is from IDE Settings, but it also no a problem.
It seems that the error is from Gradle Settings or version something.
How can I solve this problem?

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
Warning
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It's being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project.
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━

Launching lib\main.dart on SM N986N in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
lib/services/connection.g.dart:9:7: Error: The non-abstract class 'ConnectionAdapter' is missing implementations for these members:
 - TypeAdapter.typeId
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class ConnectionAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Connection> {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/hive-1.4.4+1/lib/src/registry/type_adapter.dart:7:11: Context: 'TypeAdapter.typeId' is defined here.
  int get typeId;
          ^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:179:19: Error: The method 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'inheritFromWidgetOfExactType'.
        ? context.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType(type) as _Provider<T>
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/provider-2.0.1+1/lib/src/provider.dart:180:19: Error: The method 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType' isn't defined for the class 'BuildContext'.
 - 'BuildContext' is from 'package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart' ('/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType'.
        : context.ancestorInheritedElementForWidgetOfExactType(type)?.widget
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/shared/custom_bottom_sheet.dart:291:30: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
    theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:107:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^
lib/shared/custom_show_dialog.dart:269:36: Error: Method not found: 'ButtonTheme.bar'.
      children.add(new ButtonTheme.bar(
                                   ^^^
lib/shared/custom_show_dialog.dart:635:30: Error: No named parameter with the name 'shadowThemeOnly'.
    theme: Theme.of(context, shadowThemeOnly: true),
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/theme.dart:107:20: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  static ThemeData of(BuildContext context) {
                   ^^
lib/pages/home.dart:88:7: Error: No named parameter with the name 'resizeToAvoidBottomPadding'.
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/scaffold.dart:1451:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
  const Scaffold({
        ^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 991

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running this -

1. flutter channel stable
2. flutter upgrade
3. flutter clean

To remove this warning

`Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android embedding`

You can add this to AndroidManifest.xml under activity tag.

```
<meta-data
         android:name="flutterEmbedding"
         android:value="2" />
```

This should remove the warning.